# Multiple Edit text change listner issue

Tags: android, android-edittext, changelistener

I have 2 edittext fields,and I have created 2 separate listeners for them as below.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

    email.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                       emailFlag=true;
                   }

                   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                     int count, int after) {
                   }

                   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                     int before, int count) {

                   }
                  });


    password.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                         passwordFlag=true;
                   }

                   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                     int count, int after) {
                   }

                   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                     int before, int count) {

                   }
                  });   

    }
```

**Now on a button click I just wanted to check which text field is changed** .

```
if(emailFlag){
         System.out.println("Email is changed");
             EditText emailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
              userEmailId = emailField.getText().toString();

        }

        if(passwordFlag){
             System.out.println("Password is changed");
             EditText passwordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
              userPassword = passwordField.getText().toString();

        }
```

So I have put separate flags for each of them.

But on button click I am getting for flag value as a true for both fields though I have changed/clicked on single field.

Can anybody help me out from this. Is the problem beacuse of I have added listeners in oncreate() method?

Comment: Do you set a text into your editTexts in code? If you do you fire listeners and afterTextChanged().

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes i get the TextWatcher's methods called whenever the view is initialized and set empty by Android, so you might get a false positive. I'd advice to validate if there has been a change using any of the other two methods from the TextWatcher.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with adding listeners in OnCreate method, or adding hints or setting texts from xml layout.

Make sure you have declared boolean variables as instance variables and their default value is false.